# How to select random value from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I want make "daily tip" to my website but i don't know how. I think i can use PHP and mysql database but how i can make it? Or can i make example .txt file and some php function choose dailytip from .txt file? I alredy tried this code:

Iam making website which shows daily tip to user. How I can select random value from database.

Here is what I tried:

```
<?php 
function random_tip() 
 { 
 $link = mysql_connect ("host", "user","pass", "a2955851_SW")
or die("Error " . mysql_error($link));
mysql_select_db("a2955851_SW");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `randomtip` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1()"; 
$row = mysql_query($sql, $link) 
or die("Error: ".mysql_error($link)); 
mysql_free_result($row);
mysql_close($link); 
return ($row['tip']); 
}
?>
```

Comment: What error do you get? Why are you using deprecated `mysql_*` functions?

Comment: Thanks for your username and password. You'd better call up your host and get those changed **IMMEDIATELY**

Comment: Please, _please_, ***stop using the `mysql` extension***, it's ***depreacted***, and has been for some time. [***Read the red warning on the man***](http://php.net/mysql_query), and click the links. Learn to use (and love) `PDO` and/or `mysqli` (the `i` is for _improved_). Those are the replacement extensions. PS: `$row` is not a row, it's a resource, you forgot to `mysql_fetch_assoc($row)`, which will return an assoc array containing the actual data you're after

Comment: I don't remeber my errors wan error are this: Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 20, found 16. The table is probably corrupted and i get many errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$row = mysql_query($sql, $link) 
^^^--- statement handle

return ($row['tip']); 
         ^^^^^^^--- using statement handle as if it was a row of results
```

You should have

```
$result = msyql_query(...);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['tip'];
```

instead

Note that the `mysql_*()` functions are obsolete/deprecated, and should not be used in any new code.